# How to write unit test for controller front end which submits data in database using ajax?

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

This my code for the controller.

```
   <?php

    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as HttpRequest;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress;
    use Vendor\Module\Model\MyModelFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    /**
     * This class allows to save the request in database
     * Class Index
     */


     class Index implements HttpPostActionInterface
     {

      /**
       * @var PageFactory
       */
       protected $resultPageFactory;
      /**
       * @var Json
       */
      protected $serializer;
     /**
      * @var LoggerInterface
      */
      protected $logger;
      /**
       * @var Http
       */
       protected $http;

      /**
       * @var HttpRequest
       */
       protected $httpRequest;

      /**
       * @var RemoteAddress
       */
       protected $remote;

      /**
       * @var MyModelFactory
       */
       protected $myModel;

      /**
       * @var JsonFactory
       */
       protected $resultJsonFactory;

      /**
       * @var ManagerInterface
       */
       protected $messageManager;
 
      /**
       * @var TimezoneInterface
       */
       protected $timezoneInterface;

     /**
      * Constructor
      *
      * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
      * @param LoggerInterface $logger
      * @param Http $http
      * @param HttpRequest $httpRequest
      * @param RemoteAddress $remote
      * @param MyModelFactory $myModel
      * @param JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
      * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
      * @param TimezoneInterface $timezoneInterface
      */
      public function __construct(
      PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
      LoggerInterface $logger,
      Http $http,
      HttpRequest $httpRequest,        
      RemoteAddress $remote,
      MyModelFactory $myModel,
      JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
      ManagerInterface $messageManager,
      TimezoneInterface $timezoneInterface
  ) {
      $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
      $this->logger = $logger;
      $this->http = $http;
      $this->httpRequest= $httpRequest;       
      $this->remote = $remote;
      $this->myModel = $myModel;
      $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
      $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
      $this->timezoneInterface = $timezoneInterface;
   }

    /**
     * Execute save action
     *
     * @return ResultInterface
     */
     public function execute()
    {
       $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
       $post= $this->httpRequest->getPostValue();
    
       $dateTime = $this->timezoneInterface->date()->format('Y-m- 
       d H:i:s');
       $ip = $this->remote->getRemoteAddress();
       if (empty($post['mobile'])) {
           throw new LocalizedException(__('Mobile number is 
           required'));
       }
    
    try {
        $model =  $this->myModel->create();
        $data = ['mobile'=>$post["mobile"],
             'sourc_url'=>$post["currentUrl"],
             'ip_address' => $ip,
             'created'=>$dateTime
             ];
        $model->setData($datas)->save();            
        $message =  $this->messageManager->addSuccess('form submitted succesfully.');
        return $resultJson->setData(['success' => $message]);
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        return  $resultJson->setData($e->getMessage());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e);
        return  $resultJson->setData($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller tests are usually integration tests. To unit test this controller, you should test the inputs, test that the model is instantiated and is saved and that the return result is what is expected. Basically you should test what it is suppose to do, what it actually does and especially what can break.

There are a couple of bugs in the code you need to fix first; for example, the catch assigns a string to the result JSON. Also, you shouldn't chain method calls because you need to mock the object; i.e. chain calling `setData` and `save`.

Some thing like the following:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Test\Unit\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http as HttpRequest;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager;
use Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\Index;
use Vendor\Module\Model\MyModel;
use Vendor\Module\Model\MyModelFactory;

class IndexTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    protected $controller;
    
    protected $httpRequest;
    
    protected $objectManager;
    
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);
        
        $this->httpRequest = $this->createMock(HttpRequest::class);
        
        $myModelFactory = $this->createMock(MyModelFactory::class);
        $myModelFactory->method('create')->expects($this->once())->willReturnCallback(function() {
            $myModel = $this->createMock(MyModel::class);
            $myModel->method('setData')->expects($this->once())->willReturn($myModel);
            $myModel->method('save')->expects($this->once())->willReturn($myModel);
            return $myModel;
        });
        
        $resultJsonFactory = $this->createMock(JsonFactory::class);
        $resultJsonFactory->method('create')->expects($this->once())->willReturnCallback(function(){
            return $this->objectManager->getObject(Json::class, []);
        });
        
        $this->controller = $this->objectManager->getObject(Index::class, [
            'httpRequest' => $this->httpRequest,
            'myModel' => $myModelFactory,
            'resultJsonFactory' => $resultJsonFactory
        ]);
    }
    
    public function testExecute() : void
    {
        $post = [
            'mobile' => '123-456-7890',
            'currentUrl' => 'http://www.example.com'
        ];
        $this->httpRequest->method('getPostValue')->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls($post, []);
        
        $resultJson = $this->controller->execute();
        $resultData = $resultJson->getData();
        
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('success', $resultData);

        $this->expectException();
        $this->controller->execute();
    }
}
```

Note that this is NOT a complete test. You need to test what your controller is suppose to do, what it actually does and what can break.